# How to have a 'Has Photo' (true or false) views filter

Tags: 7, views

I am looking to list a views result set based on whether it does or does not have a photo in the photo field.  I think I remember this being part of d6? d5 maybe? Regardless, I cannot find it for d7 if it exists.

If there is no such option, thoughts on how to limit a result set based on whether the field contains a photo / file or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can do that in D7/V3.3. Just add a filter field that reads like: `Content: IMAGE_FIELD_NAME:fid (not empty)`

Comment: Having some problems with this approach.  I can choose the above settings, but now, if a post has more than one image, then, in the view results, the image is repeated a number of times equal to the number of photos, so lots of duplicate content. Any thoughts on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this field as a filter criteria on your view. Choose the "User: Picture" field and check if its empty or not. Probably you need to create a relation to the user if you have a "Content" related view.